# How to create advanced check condition

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

I have an Oracle table and I would like to create a check condition like this :

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT MyTable_CHK2 CHECK (
    case Dimension 
        When 1 then 
            nvl(dimensiontype1,-1)<>-1
        when 2 then 
            nvl(dimensiontype1,-1)<>-1 and nvl(dimensiontype2,-1)<>-1
        when 3 then 
            nvl(dimensiontype1,-1)<>-1 and nvl(dimensiontype2,-1)<>-1 and nvl(dimensiontype3,-1)<>-1
        else
            true
        end
    )
disable
```

The query is not working. I'm having the error : Missing Keyword.

Anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: what should it check? constrains are not  for checking condition in pl/SQL. alter Statement ist nor a query!

Comment: The algorithm is : If the column Dimension is 1, the column DimensionType1 should not be null, if Dimension is 2, both DimensionType1 and DimensionType2 shouln't be null, and if Dimension is 3, DimensionType1, DimensionType2 & DimensionType3 should not be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want  an `AND / OR` expression

```
 ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT MyTable_CHK2 CHECK 
 (
    (  Dimension  =  1 and  nvl(dimensiontype1,-1)  <> - 1 ) OR
    (  Dimension  =  2 and  (nvl(dimensiontype1,-1) <> - 1 and nvl(dimensiontype2,-1)<> -1 ) ) OR
    (  Dimension  =  3 and  (nvl(dimensiontype1,-1) <>  -1 and nvl(dimensiontype2,-1)<>  -1 and nvl(dimensiontype3,-1) <> -1))
) disable  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check constraint should be:

```
(dimension=1 and dimensiontype1 is not null)
or (dimension=2 and dimensiontype1 is not null and dimensiontype2 is not null)
or (dimension=3 and dimensiontyp1 is not null and dimensiontype2 is not null and dimensionType 3 is not null)
```